# PuTTY is only black and white

Tags: ssh, terminal, colors, putty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set PuTTY’s appearance in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/113733/set-puttys-appearance-in-windows)

Hi.

I'm using PuTTY and lacking colours in it. Everything is black and white. Do you know how I can activate a coloured theme?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/113733/how-to-set-puttys-appearance-in-windows

Comment: I've enabled the settings for colours, but still there aren't any.